# CIFilter does not answer the kCIAttributeDescription of a custom filter

Tags: ios, cifilter

I have created a custom CIFilter and registered it in the CIFilter class with the class func registerName method. The custom filter is created and works as expected.
However CIFilter does not answer the kCIAttributeDescription that was registered.

CIFilter.localizedDescription(forFilterName: ciFilterName) does not answer the string used in the registerName method.
If the custom filter is actually instantiated it does contain the attributeDescription.

All the Apple filters in the system do answer the localizedDescription without creating the filter. The user gets information about the filter to aid in the process of filter selection.

How can a custom filter achieve the same behavior?

Here is the registration code

```
 CIFilter.registerName(kPRandom, constructor: PGLFilterConstructor(), 
            classAttributes: [
                             kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName : "Random Filters",

                              kCIAttributeFilterCategories :
                                        [ kCICategoryStillImage,
                                        kCICategoryTransition],

                              kCIAttributeDescription : "Swipe on stack Make command to add random filters to the stack. Select photos for random input with Parms Pick command"               
                          ]
        )
```

p.s the custom filter is for use in the iPad "Wills Filter Tool" app on the App Store. Exploring the world of filters is pretty amazing so the Random filter generator turns out to be a good learning and experimental tool in applying filters.

p.p.s Swift playground that demos the issue

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

// demonstrates that registering a custom filter does
// not register the kCIAttributeDescription

let kPRandom = "Random Filters"
let kCIDissolveFilter = "CIDissolveTransition"

class PGLFilterConstructor: CIFilterConstructor {
    //MARK: CIFilterConstructor protocol

    func filter(withName: String) -> CIFilter? {

        return CIFilter(name: withName)

        }
}



class PGLRandomFilterAction: CIFilter {
    // filter that answers the input as the outputImage
    // a pass thru filter

    @objc dynamic   var inputImage: CIImage?

    class func register() {
        CIFilter.registerName(kPRandom, constructor: PGLFilterConstructor(), classAttributes:
                 [
                    kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName : "Random Filters",

                    kCIAttributeFilterCategories :
                        [ kCICategoryStillImage,
                        kCICategoryTransition],

                    kCIAttributeDescription : "Swipe on stack Make command to add random filters to the stack. Select photos for random input with Parms Pick command"
                ]
        )
    }

    override var outputImage: CIImage? {
        get {
            return inputImage }
    }
}

PGLRandomFilterAction.register()
    // added to CIFilter

let randomDescription = CIFilter.localizedDescription(forFilterName: kPRandom)
let dissolveDescription = CIFilter.localizedDescription(forFilterName: kCIDissolveFilter)

// randomDescription contains the filter name. Should be the string
// set in the kCIAttributeDescription line
 
// dissolveDescription contains the expected description
```

Comment: I can't help noticing that your PGLFilterConstructor is not introspectible by Objective-C. It doesn't descend from NSObject, and its `filter(withName:)` is not marked `@objc`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I'm going to suggest that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690745/custom-filter-of-core-image-and-sig-abrt-in-xcode-9-x

Answer (score 1):

It's true that my PGLFilterConstructor is not descended from NSObject. Adding that and the @objc to the demo script does not correct the issue however.

It appears that localizedDescription is an overlooked behavior in the CIFilter area for custom registered filters. It's minor compared to all the other work going on in CoreImage so I don't think it's helpful to submit a bug report on the behavior.

So the solution is a work around.
The app customizes the UI controls based on the CIFilter.attributes with a wrapper class. Customization occurs in wrapper subclasses as appropriate to the type of filter.

For this issue add more customization in the wrapper subclasses.

In the superclass wrapper (PGLSourceFilter) return the standard description

```
class func localizedDescription(filterName: String) -> String {
    // custom subclasses should override
    guard let standardDescription = CIFilter.localizedDescription(forFilterName: filterName)
        else { return filterName }
    return standardDescription
}
```

Then the wrapper subclass can correct for the missing description

```
override class func localizedDescription(filterName: String) -> String {
    // custom subclasses should override
   return "Swipe 'Make' to add random filters. Select photos for random input on Parms 'Pick' command"
}
```